# Alarm Manager fails to repeat in Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am trying to send a notification everyday at 6 AM using Android AlarmManager. The notification works for one time and doesn't work for other days.

```
public class AlarmMsg extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
 // set the alarm
 public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmMsg.class), 0);

    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6); // hour
    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); 

    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

    if (intendedTime >= currentTime) {
        // set from today
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    } else {
        // set from next day
        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

and create the notification :

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // notification builder
}
```

and in my main activity I just call the setAlarm like this:

```
  new AlarmMsg().setAlarm(getApplicationContext());
```

this shows a notification at 6AM but it only shows 1 notification and it does not repeat for the following days. I want the notification to show every day at 6AM. Any ideas?

Comment: acquire a [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in onReceive

Answer (score 0):

If you receive alarm once then you are on the right track, just remember to use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` alarm type so the device will wake up when goes off. Also consider using `setInexactRepeating` if your alarm isn't critical.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```